# How to limit a templated function if a specialization exist?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm writing a library for which each value type can be converted to string using a `to_string()` free function.

I'd like to enable `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, _)` for all types `T` for which `to_string(T)` is valid. Here is my try:

```
namespace mylibrary {

// All my types are declared in the `mylibrary` namespace so that ADL is happy.

template <typename T>
inline std::string to_string(const T& value) {
    // Return a string for value. Doesn't really matter how.
}

template <typename T>
inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const T& value) {
    return os << to_string(value);
}

}
```

This actually works... but a bit too well: when resolving `os << to_string(value)` my templated `operator<<()` is picked up as candidate even for `std::string` which sadly makes the call ambiguous an ends up in a compiler error.

I tried using `std::enable_if<>` to conditionnaly disable my `operator<<` but sadly I couldn't get something that compiles.

How can I restrict my `operator<<()` for types for which `to_string(T)` is a valid expression ?

Alternatively, is there way to restrict my `operator<<()` for types which are defined in my namespace ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use expression-SFINAE to restrict the template overload set. For example like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename> using void_t = void;

template <typename T, typename = void_t<decltype(to_string(std::declval<T>()))>>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const T& value) {
    return os << to_string(value);
}
```

(You should probably wrap this up somehow so as not to have a visible second template parameter in your public template; users will discover and abuse it.)

Comment: When trying your sample on my compiler, I get: "test.cpp:20:12: error: use of overloaded operator '<<' is ambiguous (with operand types 'ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>') and 'std::string'". Does that work in C++11 ?

Comment: Some things that to_string works on might already have a stream insertion operator.  If that is your issue, you'll need to SFINAE that out as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
namespace details{
  template<template<class...>class,class,class...>
  struct can_apply:std::false_type{};
  template<template<class...>class Z,class...Ts>
  struct can_apply<Z,std::void_t<Z<Ts...>>,Ts...>:
    std::true_type
  {};
}
template<template<class...>class Z,class...Ts>
using can_apply=details::can_apply<Z,void,Ts...>;
```

is a small metaprogramming library that gives you the `can_apply<template, types...>` trait.  It uses C++1z `std::void_t` which is easy to write if your compiler lacks it.

```
template<class X>
using to_string_t=decltype(to_string(std::declval<X>()));
```

is a SFINAE enabled "type of calling `to_string`" (either string or error, we hope).  We stitch together:

```
template<class X>
using can_to_string=can_apply<to_string_t,X>;
```

and we have a trait `can_to_string` which is true iff you can `to_string`.  Both of the above two `using` templates shoud be in the same namespace as your `to_string` for built-in types for adl reasons.

Now we can write our `<<`:

```
template <class T,class=std::enable_if_t<can_to_string<const T&>{}>>
inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const T& value) {
  return os << to_string(value);
}
```

The modest metaprogramming library overhead makes the final code much cleaner than alternatives.

`enable_if_t` is C++14 but also easy to write in C++11.  You may have to replace `{}` with `::value` in C++11 within the `enable_if` as well.

The `result_t` using alias is one line, the `can_` alias is another, and then we have a friendly `can_` alias for almost any bit of C++ code, which allows for clean `enable_if` SFINAE.

All of this can be done on one line, but I find the resulting `<<` interface to be less than clear in what the requirements are.